# How to run a sql query for each entry by the user?

Tags: sql-server

So the user enters the policy number in the form: 2000, 2001, 2002

I need to run a query for each of those 3 policy numbers. I am not sure how to do it.

This is the code I have right now.  I was thinking about some sort of string manipulation and then use loop, but I am not sure how to do that. Can anyone please help me?

```
declare @sql1 varchar(1000)

declare @policy varchar(1000)

set @policy = '2000, 2001, 2002'

--THIS IS WHERE i NEED HELP???
set @policy = replace(@policy, ' ', '')

set @policy = '''' + replace(@policy, ',', ''',''') + ''''

print (@policy)


if  @policy <>  'null'   
set @sql1 = 
(SELECT top 1
      [MIL]     
FROM 
      [DataManagement].[dbo].[lookuptable]  where [policy] =  @policy  group by [MIL] ) 
exec (@sql1)
 print(@sql1)
```

Comment: Please only tag products used. Is it `mysql` or `sql-server`, if both please explain in question

Comment: Actually, I am sorry this is sql server

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. Are you sure you actually need one results set per item in @policy and not a single result set that matches any of the IDs? An IN query would let you get that result - sadly you can't do WHERE IN (@List), but it can be concatenated into a dynamic query (SQL injection concerns aside - make sure of your data source, but that applies to anything that's taking input like you seem to be.
2. If you declare @Policy as a user-defined table type variable, then you can pass that in as a list of IDs and simply loop through it. (More info - http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/31/sql-server-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/, https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/02/using-sql-servers-table-valued-parameters/)
3. There's no shortage of examples online of code to split a delimited string list into a table of values. That would let you do the same as I've suggested in point 2.
4. The FOR XML PATH('') trick can be used to take a table of results and flatten it into a single variable. If you join against your values table and build the SELECT query from your question as the result, you can then do a single EXEC with no need for a loop at all.

Depends what you want for your environment really. I'd use option 2 to split the string, then build a combined single query using FOR XML PATH and execute that. But for some environments the table-valued parameter and loop approach would definitely be superior.

Comment: @user3276031 Links added, HTH